# TypeError while creating a GUI app to convert feet and inches to meters

Tags: python, typeerror, pysimplegui

I am creating a python GUI app to convert feet and inches into meters. My function is in a different file from my main code file.

This is my function file: which is named - functions_feet_meter.py

```
def convert(feet, inches):
    meter = feet*0.3048 + inches*0.0254
    return meter
```

This is my main code file -

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import functions_feet_meter as function

feet_label = sg.Text('Enter feet: ')
inches_label = sg.Text('Enter inches: ')
feet_input = sg.Input(key = 'feet')
inches_input = sg.Input(key = 'inches')
convert_button = sg.Button('Convert')
output_label = sg.Text(key = 'output')

window = sg.Window('Converter',
                   layout =[[feet_label, feet_input],
                            [inches_label, inches_input],
                            [convert_button, output_label]],
                   font = ('Helvetica', 12))

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    print('EVENT', event)
    print('VALUES', values)

    feet = window['feet']
    inches = window['inches']
    result = function(feet, inches)

window.close()
```

This is the error which is shown -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Py\app1\Bonus\feet_inches to meter.py", line 25, in <module>
    result = function(feet, inches)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I expect the user will input feet and inches in the GUI app and it will show meters right by the convert button

I expect the user will input feet and inches in the GUI app and it will show meters right by the convert button

Comment: When you do `import functions_feet_meter as function`, the name "function" refers to the imported module, not to the function within it. You might want something like `from functions_feet_meter import convert`.

Comment: To get the value of an element, not `feet = window['feet']` / `inches = window['inches']`, but `feet = values['feet']` / `inches = values['inches']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import` binds a module or one of its contained objects to a name. Usually it uses the same name as the thing being imported but `as` lets you change that name.

```
import functions_feet_meter as function
```

imports the module but binds that module to the variable `function`. You want the `convert` function inside the module. Since it would be uncommon to rename that function "function", you likely want

```
from functions_feet_meter import convert
```

This imports the module and then binds its contained "convert" object instead of the module itself. And then you'd use "convert" instead of "function" later. You could also do

```
from functions_feet_meter import convert as function
```

if you really like that function name.

Answer (score -1):

How is this?
`from functions_feet_meter import convert as function` rather then `import functions_feet_meter as function`.